# Chart.js time scale showing one of the dates wrong

Tags: javascript, chart.js

For this Chart.js (master branch) line chart with an x-axis time scale, how come one of the tick labels only show up as "2016" and not the full "YYYY-MM-DD" as configured?

[image]

```js
var barChartData = {
  labels: ["2013-03-09", "2013-03-16", "2013-03-23", "2013-03-30", "2013-04-06", "2013-04-13", "2013-04-20", "2013-04-27", "2013-05-04", "2013-05-11", "2013-05-18", "2013-05-25", "2013-06-01", "2013-06-08", "2013-06-15", "2013-06-22", "2013-06-29", "2013-07-06", "2013-07-13", "2013-07-20", "2013-07-27", "2013-08-03", "2013-08-10", "2013-08-17", "2013-08-24", "2013-08-31", "2013-09-07", "2013-09-14", "2013-09-21", "2013-09-28", "2013-10-05", "2013-10-12", "2013-10-19", "2013-10-26", "2013-11-02", "2013-11-09", "2013-11-16", "2013-11-23", "2013-11-30", "2013-12-07", "2013-12-14", "2013-12-21", "2013-12-28", "2014-01-04", "2014-01-11", "2014-01-18", "2014-01-25", "2014-02-01", "2014-02-08", "2014-02-15", "2014-02-22", "2014-03-01", "2014-03-08", "2014-03-15", "2014-03-22", "2014-03-29", "2014-04-05", "2014-04-12", "2014-04-19", "2014-04-26", "2014-05-03", "2014-05-10", "2014-05-17", "2014-05-24", "2014-05-31", "2014-06-07", "2014-06-14", "2014-06-21", "2014-06-28", "2014-07-05", "2014-07-12", "2014-07-19", "2014-07-26", "2014-08-02", "2014-08-09", "2014-08-16", "2014-08-23", "2014-08-30", "2014-09-06", "2014-09-13", "2014-09-20", "2014-09-27", "2014-10-04", "2014-10-11", "2014-10-18", "2014-10-25", "2014-11-01", "2014-11-08", "2014-11-15", "2014-11-22", "2014-11-29", "2014-12-06", "2014-12-13", "2014-12-20", "2014-12-27", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-10", "2015-01-17", "2015-01-24", "2015-01-31", "2015-02-07", "2015-02-14", "2015-02-21", "2015-02-28", "2015-03-07", "2015-03-14", "2015-03-21", "2015-03-28", "2015-04-04", "2015-04-11", "2015-04-18", "2015-04-25", "2015-05-02", "2015-05-09", "2015-05-16", "2015-05-23", "2015-05-30", "2015-06-06", "2015-06-13", "2015-06-20", "2015-06-27", "2015-07-04", "2015-07-11", "2015-07-18", "2015-07-25", "2015-08-01", "2015-08-08", "2015-08-15", "2015-08-22", "2015-08-29", "2015-09-05", "2015-09-12", "2015-09-19", "2015-09-26", "2015-10-03", "2015-10-10", "2015-10-17", "2015-10-24", "2015-10-31", "2015-11-07", "2015-11-14", "2015-11-21", "2015-11-28", "2015-12-05", "2015-12-12", "2015-12-19", "2015-12-26", "2016-01-09", "2016-01-16", "2016-01-23", "2016-01-30", "2016-02-06", "2016-02-13", "2016-02-20", "2016-02-27", "2016-03-05", "2016-03-12", "2016-03-19", "2016-03-26", "2016-04-02", "2016-04-09", "2016-04-16", "2016-04-23", "2016-04-30", "2016-05-07", "2016-05-14", "2016-05-21", "2016-05-28", "2016-06-04", "2016-06-11", "2016-06-18", "2016-06-25", "2016-07-02", "2016-07-09", "2016-07-16", "2016-07-23", "2016-07-30", "2016-08-06", "2016-08-13", "2016-08-20", "2016-08-27", "2016-09-03", "2016-09-10", "2016-09-17", "2016-09-24", "2016-10-01", "2016-10-08", "2016-10-15", "2016-10-22", "2016-10-29", "2016-11-05", "2016-11-12", "2016-11-19", "2016-11-26", "2016-12-03", "2016-12-10", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-24", "2016-12-31", "2017-01-07", "2017-01-14", "2017-01-21", "2017-01-28", "2017-02-04", "2017-02-11", "2017-02-18", "2017-02-25", "2017-03-04", "2017-03-11", "2017-03-18", "2017-03-25", "2017-04-01", "2017-04-08", "2017-04-15", "2017-04-22", "2017-04-29", "2017-05-06", "2017-05-13", "2017-05-20", "2017-05-27"],
  datasets: [{
    data: [10943, 29649, 6444, 2330, 36694, 9297, 8607, 3887, 23993, 2647, 10001, 1149, 1296, 3320, 31497, 3757, 21716, 7086, 4203, 10562, 8430, 107993, 15032, 80530, 12958, 55983, 56384, 39185, 111948, 78138, 48322, 22660, 45480, 44777, 51113, 80258, 122211, 170381, 142371, 121994, 111613, 90620, 414241, 233104, 124646, 208010, 178940, 141989, 94830, 120570, 159167, 72944, 148603, 175114, 182187, 151873, 197688, 182179, 162077, 127031, 156561, 160966, 169199, 270254, 260158, 297746, 271142, 329733, 295551, 291945, 281950, 265127, 351294, 261921, 391134, 389332, 435469, 367964, 367341, 434032, 610022, 547923, 470847, 509486, 630442, 516610, 354353, 258937, 342483, 441928, 461255, 502212, 537813, 438127, 333128, 508545, 637057, 786012, 862370, 753361, 746796, 802081, 953917, 987033, 909113, 844113, 737956, 701093, 817762, 737104, 926359, 1010303, 1019052, 999567, 883027, 1105711, 954929, 1056932, 979701, 1238064, 1298420, 976489, 1093544, 1299362, 1207673, 1005359, 1070534, 1039265, 1214629, 1153509, 1206815, 1029551, 1271941, 1378490, 1224951, 1264126, 1298636, 1627311, 1988087, 1213970, 1194402, 1616617, 1349672, 1689407, 1544482, 1453755, 1090021, 1263850, 1558628, 1485323, 2213783, 1737821, 1737132, 1612459, 1921402, 2146584, 1716372, 1625193, 1726418, 2092217, 1740689, 1778557, 1743900, 2511451, 2095225, 1906606, 2072093, 2271353, 2306996, 2052930, 2522264, 2318002, 2179580, 1929402, 2058817, 1919322, 2422068, 1886848, 1814088, 1831842, 2479928, 2651487, 1993542, 1866201, 2008784, 2348564, 2362529, 1953613, 1914884, 2716617, 2312342, 2128274, 2212512, 2194987, 2497429, 2312411, 2150084, 2937512, 2700244, 3056859, 2504414, 3588714, 2845134, 2477167, 2181928, 2147184, 2891877, 3350764, 3046479, 2675718, 2517153, 3072400, 3334467, 2314341, 2460462, 3509803, 3083554, 3408975, 2883753, 5736703]
  }]
};

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "'Comic Sans MS'";
Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.radius = 0;
Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.hoverRadius = 0;

var ctx = document.getElementById("bar-chart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: barChartData,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    title: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "time",
        time: {
                    displayFormats: {
                        quarter: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
                    }
        },
        ticks: {
          minRotation: 90
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/dist/master/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="bar-chart"></canvas>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Snippet seems to work here. As for your CodePen you are using 2.6.0 -- I'm using the master branch. Thanks! http://www.chartjs.org/dist/master/Chart.bundle.min.js

Comment: For what it's worth here's my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/askhflajsf/7yped1d5/

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get CodePen to work with your script src b/c it's not https. The Fiddle will do nicely.

Comment: seems like an issue with the master branch version. use the [CDN version](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.min.js) instead.

Comment: @ℊααnd unfortunately the CDN version 2,6.0 has too many bugs related to the time scale :/

Comment: I'm hesitant to post an answer because I'm not really sure if it's a problem with the master branch or what, but there is probably some ambiguity going on between the fact that your 2016 date is both a quarter and a year (since it's January 1). You can [sort of fix it](https://jsfiddle.net/7yped1d5/1/) by adding `year: YYYY-MM-DD` in your `displayFormats`, but it still shows up with gray color rather than black. Perhaps you could try to specifically set the colors in the axis labels too, to fix that?

Comment: I think this deserves an answer :) The grey thing was me trying to target that "2016" with `major: { fontColor: "#dddddd" }` but I forgot to remove it. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, didn't even realize. Well great! I've posted an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a bug actually. If we expand the fiddle, we'll see that it's using the abbreviated dates for years, and quarters are spelled out.

[image: Chart year formats example]

However, when we shrink the chart so it appears as in your screenshot, it just so happens we see October 2013, July 2014, April 2015, and then finally we get to the beginning of January 2016, so that's the one that looks weird.

I'm guessing that's because of an ambiguity with January 1 being both a quarter and a year. The solution is to explicitly set the spelled-out date format for quarters *and* years in your chart settings:

```
new Chart(ctx, {
  //stuff and things
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      type: "time",
      time: {
        displayFormats: {
          year: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
          quarter: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
      }
      //et cetera
    }]
  }
});
```